# Haskell point free for more than one argument

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I'm trying to achieve a point free version of the following example:

```
data Person = Person String Int deriving ( Show, Eq )
data Animal = Animal Person deriving ( Show, Eq )

f :: String -> Int -> Animal
f s = Animal . Person s
-- f = Animal . Person                 -- [ 1 ]
-- f = Animal $ Person                 -- [ 2 ]
-- f = Animal . (uncurry Person) . (,) -- [ 3 ]

main = print (f "ppp" 8)
```

- Cancelling *just* the `Int` is easy, but I can't get rid of the string `s` (attempts above)
- This is a bit weird (?), because attempt `[ 1 ]` simply "peels off" a *rightmost* `s`

Comment: Don't it's not going to be easier to read. `(Animal .) . Person`

Comment: @cafce25 it works ! what's the underlying magic ?

Comment: It's a common pattern or you use a [converter](https://pointfree.io/)

Comment: There's also `fmap Animal . Person`, though that's not necessarily any more readable.

Comment: I agree about the readability - I don't understand why [ 1 ] fails - is it about associativity ?

Comment: Look that the type of `Person` as `String -> (Int -> Animal)`. That makes `Animal . Person` a function that passes the `Int -> Animal` function produced by `Person` as an argument to `Animal`. It's the difference between `Animal . (Person s)` and `(Animal . Person) s`.

Comment: Also, `f = curry (Animal . uncurry Person)`